# The mouse doesn't point to the element on login page

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, mouseevent, pywinauto

I am trying to integrate my script written in pywinauto script with the pytest-BDD framework. The problem is at login screens where the mouse doesn't focus on the password field and login button. However, if I manually focus the mouse pointer on the elements it enters the password and the login function works. Once the login is done other scripts to do various actions on the home screen of app works fine.

Here is my code:
`

```
TIMEOUT_SEC = 10

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
mylogger = logging.getLogger()

#fixtures
@pytest.fixture
def get_app_connection():
        app_conn = Application(backend='uia').connect(class_name='TFW****Explorer.***Class')
        yield app_conn 



@given(parsers.cfparse('I want to launch the Cegid Application'))
def test_launch_application():
    os.chdir("path of the application here")
    Application(backend="uia").start("**.exe")
    time.sleep(TIMEOUT_SEC)
    return True


@when(parsers.cfparse('I enter password'))
def test_enterpassword(get_app_connection):
    dlg = get_app_connection['*** - web authenticationPane']
    pywinauto.mouse.click(button='left',coords=(942,876))
    handle = dlg.child_window(auto_id="pwd", control_type="Edit")
    handle.draw_outline()
    handle.iface_value.SetValue("*****")
    pass


@then(parsers.cfparse('I click on login button'))
def test_click_loginbtn_function(get_app_connection):
    dlg = get_app_connection['*** - web authenticationPane']
    pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(1385,1219))
    dlg.child_window(title="Log in", control_type="Button").click()
`
```

I have tried using mouse movement to hover on the element coordinates the mouse doesn't move. I have read similar issues on stack but somehow it doesn't work. Kindly help

Comment: As I remember, `.SetValue("***")` doesn't require to have edit box in focus. It brings it to focus automatically. I would understand of there is a problem with `type_keys("***", with_spaces=True)` but I don't see it in the code. Please provide more details.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov , I understood `iface_value.SetValue("***")` would automatically set the value like you said, my bad that this is line is commented in the code(updated now). Hence, I did not include type_keys to set the password. I have tried `dlg.set_text("****",pos_start=None,pos_end=None)` which throws error `raise AttributeError("Neither GUI element (wrapper) " \
      AttributeError: Neither GUI element (wrapper) nor wrapper method 'set_text' were found (typo?)`

Comment: I have tried various solutions given over the internet still doesnt work

Comment: `dlg.set_text` is not a good idea. First `DialogWrapper` has no method `set_text` (it's for `EditWrapper` only). I still don't understand which line fails.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, I got this working by focusing the mouse on the element coordinate.using`pywinauto.mouse.move(coords=(x, y))`.Once the mouse is focused `handle = dlg.child_window(auto_id="pwd", control_type="Edit")
    handle.iface_value.SetValue("*****")` works absolutely fine. I believe its application issue at the login page. Since all other edit type elements are focused when the application opens Home screen.

Comment: OK, please post this as an answer and mark as accepted. It's OK to accept your own answer as well. Thanks!